# Counterexample in theory of tensorproducts of modules

Tags: modules, tensor-products

This is remark $5.10$ in the (excellent) text https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=R/pR$ as an $R-$module. How could one prove that, if $M^{\vee}$ is the dual of $M$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)$ is the $R-$module of $R$-endomorphisms of $M$, $M^{\vee}\cong M$, $M\bigotimes_R M \cong M$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)\cong M$.

Comment: Basically since everything about $M$ is completely determined by what that thing does to $1=1+pR\in M$ you can easily calculate these.

Comment: Shouldn't that rather lead to $M^{\vee}\cong R$ then?

Comment: No, since the image of an element of $M^{\vee}$ can only contain elements $x$ of $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ for which $p.x=0$

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** Let $M:=R/(p)$ and let $I:=(p) \subseteq R$. We get

$$M\otimes_R M \cong R/I\otimes_R R/I \cong R/I/(IR/I) \cong R/I/(0) \cong R/I \cong M.$$

In general for any $A$-module $M$ it follows $A/I\otimes_A M \cong M/IM$. The other formulas follow using similar methods.